# :enabled vs <input> element default styles

Tags: html, css

Why is the :enabled pseudo-class needed when the input element is active and available by default?

**CSS**

```
.useable {
  background: maroon;
}
:enabled {
  background: green;
}

:disabled {
  background: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <input class="useable" type="text"> <!-- :enabled pseudo-class look like a similar default input usage so what's the diff. -->
```

Comment: because it could not if for example you set it as disabled. That's why you have a tool (the `:enabled` pseudo class) to intercept all elements that _"can be activated or accept focus"_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:enabled so for example you could decide a style rule for those elements and one for the disabled ones

Comment: of course if instead you meant why the rule addressing the `:enabled` elements is overriding the rule selecting `.useable` it's because any css property (`background`) set by different sources (a css rule or inline styling) on the same element will follow the precedence given by the specificity of the selector and which one comes after. So in your case the second rule comes after the first and takes precedence over the first one. If you inverted the order it would behave differently

Answer (score -1):

It may be desirable to specify form elements that can and cannot be used in a form. In this case, these selectors are used to express which element the visitor can use and which cannot.